# linq convertall for multiple field

Tags: c#, linq

I have to get two field from datatable. And then I should check one.
"listIDStr" keep list of userID that is not uniqe. So I have to use "ID that is primary key when I update a row.

```
List<string> listIDStr = new List<string>();
...
var sqlData = SqlDataBase.SqlGetTable("SELECT ID,UserID FROM TBL_UserT WHERE SID = " + 4663 + " AND UserID = '" + UserID + "'")
                          .AsEnumerable()
                          .ToList()
                          .ConvertAll(x=>x.Field<string>("UserID"))
                          .ToList();

List<string> Cikan = sqlData.Where(x => !listIDStr.Contains(x)).ToList();
List<string> Eklenen = listIDStr.Where(x => !sqlData.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

The above code is running for one field.But  I want to get "ID" together with "UserID". Does anyone have a good idea how it does ?

Comment: Sorry for the off topic question here but I am a curious person.
How do you access `SqlDataBase.SqlGetTable();`? Is it a custom class? I tried pasting it to no avail. Again sorry for the OT :)

Comment: Yes SqlDataBase is a class and SqlGetTable is a function. :)

Comment: Is it a custom class? I can't call if from my VWD2010

Comment: Static class. You can just static class as this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use anonymous types, [here is the MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

```
var dtEnumerable = SqlDataBase.SqlGetTable("SELECT ID,UserID FROM TBL_UserT WHERE SID = " + 4663 + " AND UserID = '" + UserID + "'").AsEnumerable().ToList();

var newVariable = dtEnumerable.Select(x => new { UserID = x.Field<string>("UserID"), ID = x.Field<string>("ID") });
//Get new/old
var states = newVariable.Select(x => new { IsNew = !listIDStr.Contains(x.UserId), IsUpdate = listIDSTr.Contains(x.UserID), ID = x.UserID });
var updates = states.Where(x => x.IsUpdate).Select(x => x.UserID);
var newIds = states.Where(x => x.IsNew).Select(x => x.UserID);
//We now have access to both!
string firstUserID = newVariable.First().UserID;
string firstID = newVariable.First().ID;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I haven't tried yet.Because I can't write "Cikan" and "Eklenen". Can you write "Cikan" and "Eklenen".

Comment: @zeitgeist you would only need one `List<string>` now due to the combination? I don't understand those variable names, so you might have to explain what exactly you want

Comment: "Cikan" is outgoing user. "Eklenen" is new user.So I learn this "user is new?" or "user is outgoing?".

Comment: @zeitgeist I can't understand how with the code that I have changed there is a method for me to determine either of these? What is `listIDstr`?

Comment: "listIDstr" is contains "UserID" of all my followers list in twitter. I just check who follow me new and who unfollow me. :)

Comment: @zeitgeist I think that is what you need (see the `//Get new/old` comment)

Comment: Yeap I need to see who new user and old user.

Comment: Shorlty "Eklenen" is in listIDStr not in "sqlData"  and "Cikan" is in sqldata not in "listIDStr ".

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want to "project" the data coming back into a different kind of object, perhaps even an anonymous one if you're not planning on passing it outside the method.

**Anonymous object**

```
var user = SqlDataBase.SqlGetTable("select Id, Name from User where ...")
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .ToList()
                      .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Name })
                      .SingleOrDefault();

int userId = user.Id;
string username = user.Name;
```

**Strongly-typed object**

```
var user = SqlDataBase.SqlGetTable("select Id, Name from User where ...")
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .ToList()
                      .Select(x => new UserViewModel { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name })
                      .SingleOrDefault();

int userId = user.Id;
string username = user.Name;
```